# How to make a svg shape with circular gradient fill?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make svg shapes with a circular gradient fill. Using `<radialGradient>` makes elliptical gradient fill as opposed to circular gradients as shown in [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sunnysinghthakran/kf58h/).

What i am looking for instead is a gradient fill similar to this:

[image]

Basically i need circular gradient fills irrespective of the svg shape. Can anyone suggest me a way to proceed?

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: You may need to [specify many properties](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kf58h/1/) to achieve that, [according to W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/pservers.html#RadialGradients).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
<svg>
  <defs>

    <radialGradient
       id="grad1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:hsl(212,52%,15%); "/>
            <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:hsl(212,52%,35%); "/>
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:hsl(212,52%,52%); "/>
    </radialGradient>

  </defs>

  <rect height="400" width="600" x="100" y="220" style="fill:url(#grad1);"></rect>

</svg>
```

Especially watch `userSpaceOnUse` It makes the gradient independent to the object. The downside is when you move your object around, you need to move the gradient as well.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/2Nc4b/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/kf58h/2/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
div{background: #264a75; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #264a75 2%, #4176b6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(2%,#264a75), color-stop(100%,#4176b6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #264a75 2%,#4176b6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #264a75 2%,#4176b6 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #264a75 2%,#4176b6 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #264a75 2%,#4176b6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#264a75', endColorstr='#4176b6',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */ width:300px; height:150px; border:3px solid #385d8a;}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Its a div based pure css solution. - @osi

Comment: Ok, I thought TS was looking for a SVG solution

Comment: The `background` property only has an effect on the outermost svg element ATM. However it will become possible to use css gradients in the `fill` property in SVG2, see https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint.